# How to limit TextField maximum count of words

Tags: flutter

I want to make a feature like the picture, and it needs to limit the count of input value separated by space.
[image]

I found many solutions used **maxLength**, but is not working in this case.

Then I tried another way like

```
  onChanged: (String v) {
    // if reach the maximum count
    _controller.text = v.substring(0, _text);
  },
```

but the input behavior became weird.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `TextInputFormatter`:

```
class MaxWordTextInputFormater extends TextInputFormatter {
  final int maxWords;
  final ValueChanged<int>? currentLength;

  MaxWordTextInputFormater({this.maxWords = 1, this.currentLength});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    int count = 0;
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
      count = 0;
    } else {
      count = newValue.text.trim().split(RegexUtil.spaceOrNewLine).length;
    }
    if (count > maxWords) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    currentLength?.call(count);
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

[My Git demo](https://github.com/sayhellotogithub/textfield_length_limit_word).

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the following ways.

1. using a `TextFormField` with a `validator`.

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (text) {
    if (text.split(' ').length > max_limit) {
      return 'Reached max words';
    }
    return null;
  },
);
```

2. Add a decoration which will show an error if the limit is crossed.

```
TextField(
  controller: _text,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Enter 5 words',
    errorText: _validate ? 'You have entered more than 5 words' : null,
  ),
);
```

On your `OnChanged()` -> update the `_validate` variable based on your condition.

Comment: Thank you, it's awesome! Dose this way can disable user input if the limit is crossed ?

Comment: yes, you can disable the text field? But you'll have to add a way to give option to user to edit the text again..if that is what you want.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please mark is as correct or that it might help others in community, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mask_text_input_formatter, https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter to help you to separate the word format that you want to split

```
TextField(inputFormatters: [
 MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '+# (###) ###-##-##', filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[0- 
 9]') });

])
```